# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'type' and 'int'

Tags: python, function

```py
# To input x show if x is even or odd
def main():
    x = int(input("What is x? "))
    if is_even():
        print("x is even.")
    else:
        print("x is odd.")    
    # To see if x is even or odd

def is_even(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

main()
```

I have been having troubles and I do not know the issue. I even did exactly what the tutor did in the course and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: The title of this question is not the error message you received, and the one you received spells out exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Realize that `input` returns a string, so `x` will be `str` and not `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_even()` accepts one positional argument `n`. While calling `is_even()` you must pass the value to it. e.g.

```
x = int(input("What is x? "))
if is_even(x): # value of x is passed to the is_even function
    print("x is even.")
else:
    print("x is odd.")
```

This is because when declaring the `is_even()` function, you're accepting `n` as an argument. Another possible solution could be to use default parameters:

```
def is_even(n=2):
    pass # your logic here
```

In the above example, the value of `n` was optional, if the value wasn't passed it would be set to `2` by default.

Answer (score 0):

you define your function as requiring a argument, `def is_even(n)`.  when you use it, `if is_even()` you do not give the required argument.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I disagree. it is concise. bad bot.